# How can SharePoint search be configured to return results for Microsoft Teams chat (messages)?

Tags: search, search-results, enterprise-search, result-source, microsoft-teams

Can Microsoft Teams chat (aka messages) be added as a result source in SharePoint?

The underlying need is a comprehensive search across all of our 0365 content. The Teams search experience is poor and I've seen recommendations to use Sharepoint's enterprise search instead, but then can't see how to include everything in the index. Document search is working fine.

I can find general information on result sources e.g. 
[Understanding result sources for search in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/dn186229.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - but no specific references to Microsoft Teams chat.

***edit:** not sure if this is more of a Sharepoint question or a Teams question...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to configure. It is up to Microsoft to provide Search Experiences that meet the user requirements. Ideally they would think about search and discovery when they create new features and workloads. Sadly, they don't always.

You can voice your opinion here: [Customer Feedback for Microsoft Office 365](https://office365.uservoice.com). Be as specific as you can.